# Compare different sizes arrays

Tags: android, arrays, math, curve

I'm getting coordinates from the phone accelerometer, after that this 3 axis coordinates I need to compare them to my data base. They don't need to be exactly the same because that would be impossible, but I need to know if they follow the same path.

I've been trying to store the coordinates in an array and compare it to my database array, but most of the time the arrays have different sizes and that makes sense.

Should I need to compare arrays coordinates ? Or should I calculate a curve using these coordinates and then compare how close these curves are ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of tour data?

Comment: How many points your predefined path in the DB has? Can you just load it into the memory and do all calculations there? Also what is the format of your data? Is this GPS location? If you really use accelerometer, I'm not sure I understand what exactly you get.